# looping through multiple generic tables using MySQL-view

Tags: mysql

I got several (logging) tables, one for each month, 12 for a whole year.
Table pattern is: usage_YYYY_MM (so that'd be: usage_2012_11, usage_2012_12, usage_2013_01 etc)

What I want to do is combine the contents of these tables in a single view. Sometimes for a whole year, sometimes for the past N months.. 
In the view I would be using something similar to this:

```
(SELECT order_id, SUM(`usage`) as total, created FROM usage_2012_05 GROUP BY order_id)
UNION ALL
(SELECT order_id, SUM(`usage`) as total, created FROM usage_2012_06 GROUP BY order_id)
UNION ALL
(SELECT order_id, SUM(`usage`) as total, created FROM usage_2012_07 GROUP BY order_id)
ORDER BY created;
```

Since I don't want to be adding new tables to a specific view each month, I had thought to do this in a loop. I've been snooping around and already understand I should be using something like SELECT GROUP_CONCAT. This is what I got so far:

```
SET @resultQuery = NULL;

SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(
    CONCAT('SELECT order_id, `usage` as used, created FROM ', table_name )
    SEPARATOR '\r\nUNION\r\n'
  )
INTO
  @resultQuery
FROM
  information_schema.`TABLES`
WHERE
  table_name LIKE "usage_%" 
ORDER BY 
    table_name DESC LIMIT 2;

PREPARE stmt FROM @resultQuery;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Now, although this DOES give me the whole data-set, the last bit (ORDER BY table_name DESC LIMIT 2) doesn't seem to work... So, I'm still not entirely there..

Is there a reason why the ORDER BY DESC and LIMIT don't work? Should I approach this differently?

BTW: not looking for well meant remarks about normalization in regards to the "usage_" tables.. We are well aware of this but have specific (legacy) reasons to want them like this..

Comment: I'll keep this bookmarked to show people what happens when you don't want to use partitioning. No offense meant, but this is a perfect example of why you don't want to reinvent hot water (even though I do understand how legacy reasons can mess up the whole project). Good luck getting the solution! :)

Comment: yeah, legacy is my main nightmare here.. Legacy code and black boxes..

Comment: What do you mean - 'doesn't seem to work...'?

Comment: the 'order by' doesn't seem to order the list (tried ASC and DESC and was expecting different row order)
the 'limit' doesn't seem to limit anything (result-sets are the same, regardless of limit statement.

I had hoped to use the order_by and limit statement to be able to get the latest two/three or six month periods..